# Dart DateTime.difference() working different for Android 7.1.1 and later

Tags: android, dart

Running the following code on emulator with Android 7.1.1, I get 29. The same code on Android 9 I get 30.

```dart
DateTime start = DateTime(2020, 9, 30);
DateTime end = DateTime(2020, 10, 30);

end.difference(start).inDays;
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you set the locale to the same on each device? It could be daylight saving time and the differences comes from different locales.

Comment: Yes, same locale. And both DateTime set to "00:00:00"

Comment: Android 7 probably was not updated to properly recognize Brazil's recent-ish change to get rid of DST.  When Android 7 was released (c. 2016), Brazil's DST started in October.

Comment: Yes @jamesdlin! You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested by @julemand101, I started looking for anything related to daylight saving issues and I realized that the difference was 719 hours in Android 7.1.1 and 720 in Android 9. It was rounding down to 29 (instead 30) the difference in days.

Checking the date_time.dart I've found the following:

````dart
  /**
   * Constructs a [DateTime] instance specified in the UTC time zone.
   *
   * ```
   * var moonLanding = new DateTime.utc(1969, 7, 20, 20, 18, 04);
   * ```
   *
   * When dealing with dates or historic events prefer to use UTC DateTimes,
   * since they are unaffected by daylight-saving changes and are unaffected
   * by the local timezone.
   */
````

So converting date to utc before calculating the difference worked fine for me.